# json.Marshal(): json: error calling MarshalJSON for type msgraph.Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

What specific syntax or configuration changes must be made in order to resolve the error below in which terraform is failing to create an instance of `azuread_application`?

**THE CODE:**

The terraform code that is triggering the error when `terraform apply` is run is as follows:

```
variable "tenantId" { }
variable "clientId" { }
variable "clientSecret" { }
variable "instanceName" { }

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "2.5.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azuread" {
  tenant_id       = var.tenantId
  client_id       = var.clientId
  client_secret   = var.clientSecret
}

resource "azuread_application" "appRegistration" {
  display_name = var.instanceName
  app_role {
    allowed_member_types = ["User", "Application"]
    description          = "Admins can manage roles and perform all task actions"
    display_name         = "Admin"
    enabled              = true
    id                   = "1b19509b-32b1-4e9f-b71d-4992aa991967"
    value                = "admin"
  }
}
```

**THE ERROR:**

The error and log output that result from running the above code with `terraform apply` are:

```
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [DEBUG] module.ad-admin.azuread_application.appRegistration:
 apply errored, but we're indicating that via the Error pointer rather than returning it:
 Could not create application: json.Marshal():
 json: error calling MarshalJSON for type msgraph.Application:
 json: error calling MarshalJSON for type *msgraph.Owners: marshaling Owners: encountered DirectoryObject with nil ODataId

2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] EvalMaybeTainted: module.ad-admin.azuread_application.appRegistration encountered an error during creation, so it is now marked as tainted
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] EvalWriteState: removing state object for module.ad-admin.azuread_application.appRegistration
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] EvalApplyProvisioners: azuread_application.appRegistration has no state, so skipping provisioners
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] EvalMaybeTainted: module.ad-admin.azuread_application.appRegistration encountered an error during creation, so it is now marked as tainted
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] EvalWriteState: removing state object for module.ad-admin.azuread_application.appRegistration
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] vertex "module.ad-admin.azuread_application.appRegistration": visit complete

2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "module.ad-admin.output.application_id (expand)" errored, so skipping
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "module.ad-admin.azuread_service_principal.appRegistrationSP" errored, so skipping
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "output.application_id" errored, so skipping
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "module.ad-admin.output.appId (expand)" errored, so skipping
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "module.ad-admin.azuread_service_principal_password.appRegistrationSP_pwd" errored, so skipping
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "output.appId" errored, so skipping
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "module.ad-admin.azurerm_role_assignment.appRegistrationSP_role_assignment_vault" errored, so skipping
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "module.ad-admin.azurerm_role_assignment.appRegistrationSP_role_assignment" errored, so skipping
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "module.ad-admin.provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread\"] (close)" errored, so skipping
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "module.ad-admin.provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm\"] (close)" errored, so skipping
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "module.ad-admin (close)" errored, so skipping
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" errored, so skipping
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "root" errored, so skipping
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: creating backup snapshot at terraform.tfstate.backup
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: state has changed since last snapshot, so incrementing serial to 391
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: writing snapshot at terraform.tfstate
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: removing lock metadata file .terraform.tfstate.lock.info

Error: Could not create application

  on ..\..\..\..\modules\ad-admin\active-directory.tf line 69, in resource "azuread_application" "appRegistration":
  69: resource "azuread_application" "appRegistration" {

json.Marshal(): json: error calling MarshalJSON for type msgraph.Application:
json: error calling MarshalJSON for type *msgraph.Owners: marshaling Owners:
2021/10/05 17:47:18 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: unlocked by closing terraform.tfstate
encountered DirectoryObject with nil ODataId
```

`terraform -version` gives:

Terraform v1.0.8
on windows_amd64

Comment: Are you using latest versions of TF and azure provider?

Comment: Oh I see. This is rather old provider. Have you check with the latest ones?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what's happening?

Comment: @Marcin  Thank you for following up.  I put the solution as an edit to your answer and marked it as accepted to help others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a **bug**, reported as GitHub issue:

- [Error: ODataId was nil when creating an azuread_group resource #588](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/issues/588)

The resolution to the problem in the OP is to upgrade the version from `2.5.0` to `2.6.0` in the `required_providers` block from the code in the OP above as follows:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "2.6.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix was released, and it is working for me.

[Workaround for corrupted or missing @odata.id for directory objects](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/pull/616)